# Need help setting logic operator in if statement

Tags: javascript, html

It should be a fairly standard logic, but for some reason, I couldn't get it to work.

I want the code to display a warning message only when a certain combination of selections have been made. The warning text will display when Pluto is selected, regardless of which lander has been selected. I only intend for it to happen when pluto is selected with the NonReusableLanders.

```js
//Lander Selection
var ReUsable = false;

function LanderSelect() {
  if (document.getElementById('NonReUse').checked) {
    ReUsable = false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('ReUse').checked) {
    ReUsable = true;
  }
}
//List of Moons
const Moons = {
  Earth: ["Luna"],
  Mars: ["", "Phobos", "Deimos"],
  Jupiter: ["Metis", "Amalthea", "Thebe", "Io", "Europa", "Ganymede", "Callisto", "Himalia", "Lysithea", "Elara"],
  Saturn: ["Mimas", "Enceladus", "Tethys", "Dione", "Rhea", "Titan", "Iapetus", "Hyperion", "Phoebe", "Janus"],
  Uranus: ["Titania", "Oberon", "Ariel", "Umbriel", "Miranda", "Puck", "Sycorax", "Portia", "Juliet", "Belinda"],
  Neptune: ["Triton", "Proteus", "Nereld", "Larissa", "Galatea", "Despina", "Thalassa", "Naiad", "Halimede", "Neso"],
  Pluto: ["Charon", "Styx", "Nix", "Kerbos", "Hydra"]
}
//Launch Moon
function LaunchMoonSelect(value) {
  var MoonOptions = "";
  for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
    MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("LaunchMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
}
//Des Moon Selector
function DesMoonSelect(value) {
  if (value != "Pluto") {
    document.getElementById("DesWarning").style.display = "none";
    var MoonOptions = "";
    for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
      MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("DestMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
  }
  
  else {
    document.getElementById("DesWarning").style.display = "block";
    var MoonOptions = "";
    for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
      MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("DestMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
NonReusable Landers <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="NonReUse" onclick="LanderSelect()" value="ture"></input>
Reusable Landers <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="ReUse" onclick="LanderSelect()"></input>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
  <tr style="height: 20px;">
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;vertical-align:middle">Destination</td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;">Planet: </br>
      <select class="select" id="DestPlan" onChange="DesMoonSelect(this.value);">
        <option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>
        <option value="Venus">Venus</option>
        <option value="Earth" selected>Earth</option>
        <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
        <option value="Jupiter">Jupiter</option>
        <option value="Saturn">Saturn</option>
        <option value="Uranus">Uranus</option>
        <option value="Neptune">Neptune</option>
        <option value="Pluto">Pluto</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;"> Moon: </br>
      <select class="select" id="DestMoon">
        <option value="Luna" selected style="color:white">Luna</option>
      </select>
      <p id="DesWarning" style="color:red; display:none;"><strong>Can't Reach!!</Strong></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

And after I insert the `if else{...}` part of the code, the moon selection doesn't even work let alone the warning text

```js
//Lander Selection
var ReUsable = false;

function LanderSelect() {
  if (document.getElementById('NonReUse').checked) {
    ReUsable = false;
  } else if (document.getElementById('ReUse').checked) {
    ReUsable = true;
  }
}
//List of Moons
const Moons = {
  Earth: ["Luna"],
  Mars: ["", "Phobos", "Deimos"],
  Jupiter: ["Metis", "Amalthea", "Thebe", "Io", "Europa", "Ganymede", "Callisto", "Himalia", "Lysithea", "Elara"],
  Saturn: ["Mimas", "Enceladus", "Tethys", "Dione", "Rhea", "Titan", "Iapetus", "Hyperion", "Phoebe", "Janus"],
  Uranus: ["Titania", "Oberon", "Ariel", "Umbriel", "Miranda", "Puck", "Sycorax", "Portia", "Juliet", "Belinda"],
  Neptune: ["Triton", "Proteus", "Nereld", "Larissa", "Galatea", "Despina", "Thalassa", "Naiad", "Halimede", "Neso"],
  Pluto: ["Charon", "Styx", "Nix", "Kerbos", "Hydra"]
}
//Launch Moon
function LaunchMoonSelect(value) {
  var MoonOptions = "";
  for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
    MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("LaunchMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
}
//Des Moon Selector
function DesMoonSelect(value) {
  if (value != "Pluto") {
    document.getElementById("DesWarning").style.display = "none";
    var MoonOptions = "";
    for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
      MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("DestMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
  }
   else if(ReUsable == true) {
document.getElementById("DesWarning").style.display = "none";
var MoonOptions = "";
for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
  MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("DestMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;}
  else {
    document.getElementById("DesWarning").style.display = "block";
    var MoonOptions = "";
    for (MoonId in Moons[value]) {
      MoonOptions += "<option>" + Moons[value][MoonId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("DestMoon").innerHTML = MoonOptions;
  }
}
```

```html
NonReusable Landers <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="NonReUse" onclick="LanderSelect()" value="ture"></input>
Reusable Landers <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="ReUse" onclick="LanderSelect()"></input>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1">
  <tr style="height: 20px;">
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;vertical-align:middle">Destination</td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;">Planet: </br>
      <select class="select" id="DestPlan" onChange="DesMoonSelect(this.value);">
        <option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>
        <option value="Venus">Venus</option>
        <option value="Earth" selected>Earth</option>
        <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
        <option value="Jupiter">Jupiter</option>
        <option value="Saturn">Saturn</option>
        <option value="Uranus">Uranus</option>
        <option value="Neptune">Neptune</option>
        <option value="Pluto">Pluto</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align: center;"> Moon: </br>
      <select class="select" id="DestMoon">
        <option value="Luna" selected style="color:white">Luna</option>
      </select>
      <p id="DesWarning" style="color:red; display:none;"><strong>Can't Reach!!</Strong></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

P.S. I've only learned basic JS so far, if this needs the expanded libraries, please explain in detail how some of the components work.
P.P.S Why does the radio input type need `name=""` for it to function like a flipflop?
P.P.P.S How do I set the initial state for the radio checkbox?

Comment: This is weird... It works in the code snippet, but when I try to run the html file in firefox, the second dropdown list is still broken. Help!

Answer (score 1):

For the `else if { ... }` you placed `if else` instead which will cause a syntax error. I suggest using IDE or Text Editor(I would recommend VSCode or Atom), that way the editor will spot typos/syntax mistakes.

> How do I set the initial state for the radio checkbox?

For the setting input default value, assign it to `value` attribute inside input tag:

```html
<input type="text" value='Bob'>
```

> Why does the radio input type need `name=""` for it to function like a flipflop?

`name` attribute on input tag identifies the input value, when the form is submitted to the server.

> I've only learned basic JS so far, if this needs the expanded libraries, please explain in detail how some of the components work.

Before focusing on learning libraries, you mentioned how you're learning basic JS, I suggest keep going on that track and get comfortable learning how to use plain JS. If you jump into learning libraries without knowing the basics of how JS works, you'll have a tough time.

Comment: I'm currently using note++, and i've selected the language to JavaScript. it's not showing errors... W3School isn't much of help in this situation.

Comment: You should check out [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), and start with the fundamentals. The fundamentals also has a section on Code editors.